# having different values in the properties of the same object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, properties

why i have a value the same object in an array but when i select it like this arr[0] i find in the console diffrent values

```js
class Player {
    constructor(x){
        this.x = x
    }
    move(code){
        if(code==="ArrowUp"){
                this.x +=1;
                fn();
        };
        players[0] = player;
    }
};
let players = [];
let player = new Player(1);
function fn() {
console.log(player,players[0])
}
```

so when i add an event click for example on the document
that when it happen the function of event will call player.move(e.code) and pass as an argument e.code
// the value of x of first object in the printed players array is different from the x in the object player1 and players[0]

Comment: The code in your question is incomplete and we can't debug it. What is `Item`? What is `fn`? What is `player1`? Why aren't you pushing anything into that array? We need a [mcve] to be able see clearly what the issue is. What is your code meant to do?

Comment: i have edited the code , and deleted extra informations , and fn is a ordinary function , actually this is just a simplified code of a piece of big code from my app , i just wanted to know what are the situations where an object have diffrent values , thank you

Comment: What two values are being printed?

Comment: actually i added an event click on the document and call player.move(event.code) so if you clickid arrow up it will add 1 to player.x then add it to the array players , so when i print them the first time i get the same value of x but in the second time i get different values

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you're printing `[] undefined`?

I reworked your code to give that output:

```
class Player {
    constructor(x){
        this.x = x
    }
    move(code){
        if(code==="ArrowUp"){
                this.x +=1;
                fn();
        };
        players[0] = player;
    }
};
let players = [];
let player = new Player(1);
player.move("ArrowUp");
function fn() {
    console.log(players,players[0])
}
```

What happens is inside `player`, the `code` is `"ArrowUp"`, triggering the code inside the `if` to execute. That code increments `player.x` to `2`. By this time, no code has changed anything to do with `players`, the array, so it is still an empty array `[]`. This is still the case when `fn` is called after that change to `player`. The first value printed comes from `players` being an empty array. The `undefined` comes from indexing an empty array at 0 (the first element in the array) gives undefined when there is no object there. The result is `[] undefined`.

Afterward, `players[0] = player` is ran, putting `player` at the 0th position in the array. If we run `fn` at this point, it should output: `[ Player { x: 2 } ] Player { x: 2 }`. You will get this behavior by putting an `fn` after `players[0] = player` or by putting it after `player.move("ArrowUp");`.